# How to fix subquity crash with autoinstall ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso using seed.iso

Tags: server, automation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server automatically in Hyper-V from this iso: `ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso`
I use the VOLUME method to pass the cloud-init cfg so I have created a `seed.iso` loaded in a second virtual-dvd-drive for the autoinstall (the first dvd holds the live-server.iso).

This is the view of the VM screen on the hypervisor.  [output in hypervisor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsNU5.png)

I also have the crash file but it's quite large so I'll have to link it [crash report file](https://wiki.politick.ca/download/attachments/49905696/1655186003.648901463.unknown.crash?version=1&modificationDate=1655188041577&api=v2).   But this is the main error in the crash report:  `FAIL: no identity data provided`.  I tried adding "" around the crypted `Password:` in case the $ in the string would confuse some interpreter, but that didn't help.  So I don't know why it claims that there is no identity.

```
 2022-06-14 05:53:23,647 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/Identity/apply_autoinstall_config: FAIL: no identity data provided
 2022-06-14 05:53:23,647 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/apply_autoinstall_config: FAIL: no identity data provided
 2022-06-14 05:53:23,647 ERROR subiquity.server.server:416 top level error
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subiquity/server/server.py", line 625, in start
     await self.apply_autoinstall_config()
   File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subiquitycore/context.py", line 148, in decorated_async
     return await meth(self, **kw)
   File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subiquity/server/server.py", line 467, in apply_autoinstall_config
     await controller.apply_autoinstall_config()
   File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subiquitycore/context.py", line 148, in decorated_async
     return await meth(self, **kw)
   File "/snap/subiquity/3359/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subiquity/server/controllers/identity.py", line 60, in apply_autoinstall_config
     raise Exception("no identity data provided")
 Exception: no identity data provided
```

I use the user-data for the config & I have a 0 byte meta-data file (empty but there).

Here is the content of my user-data.  I have tried multiple combination `update yes-no` and different `apt sources` and they all end the same way with the crash of subquity.  I started with my own config, but I've converged to your example here: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall
to try to eliminate underlying problems I could have introduced.

Kind Regards,
Martin Politick.  June 2022.

user-data

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1

#early-commands:
#    - ping -c1 198.168.10.2
locale: en_US.UTF-8
refresh-installer:
  update: yes
keyboard:
    layout: us
    variant: ""
network:
    network:
        version: 2
        ethernets:
            eth0:
               dhcp4: yes
#proxy: http://squid.internal:3128/
apt:
    preserve_sources_list: true
    primary:
        - arches: [default]
          uri: http://repo.internal/
#        - arches: [i386, amd64]
#          uri: "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"
#        - arches: [default]
#          uri: "http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports"
#    geoip: true

#    sources:
#        my-ppa.list:
#            source: "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/curtin-dev/test-archive/ubuntu $RELEASE main"
#            keyid: B59D 5F15 97A5 04B7 E230  6DCA 0620 BBCF 0368 3F77
storage:
    layout:
        name: lvm
identity:
    hostname: gold
    username: wenco
    password: $6$e8JJnlcSYAlKfoQ9$BlEJxE0ToJzT3Ic1NJjsjPm87zyN./1faw32/TQnj9z6GTobR/r6Tn2q0OsESmZfC3ieeNokupExLvGEe.zOp.
ssh:
    install-server: yes
    authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa 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
    allow-pw: no
#snaps:
#    - name: go
#      channel: 1.14/stable
#      classic: true
#debconf-selections: |
#    bind9      bind9/run-resolvconf    boolean false
packages:
    - curl

user-data:
    disable_root: false
late-commands:
    - sed -ie 's/GRUB_TIMEOUT=.*/GRUB_TIMEOUT=5/' /target/etc/default/grub
#error-commands:
#    - tar c /var/log/installer | nc 192.168.0.1 1000
reporting:
 builtin:
  type: print
```

**CRASH FILE**

It does not fit here ...
You should be able to get it here:
https://wiki.politick.ca/download/attachments/49905696/1655186003.648901463.unknown.crash?version=1&modificationDate=1655188041577&api=v2

[link to creah report file](https://wiki.politick.ca/download/attachments/49905696/1655186003.648901463.unknown.crash?version=1&modificationDate=1655188041577&api=v2)

Comment: Did your `user-data` post properly?  If it is accurate then you are missing a lot of indentation.

Comment: Once in the crash prompt, I can `cloud-init query userdata` and I see the output of the user-data above.  `cloud-init status` also says `status: done`.  Also `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` finished with a modules-final: SUCCESS: running modules for final

Comment: All of the keys used for autoinstall need to be indented under the `autoinstall` block like your `version` key.  Look at sample `user-data` files to see examples of how the keys are formatted.

Comment: Yes...
`# echo $( removeProfanityMacro( $Comment ))
The indentation was the problem.  This is why I hate yaml so intensely.  I even tried cloud-init devel schema user-data and it returned valid... `

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

The yaml indentation is wrong.
All the autoinstall key:value pairs must be placed under the autoinstall scope.

### How it happened

I've cut & pasted the example here :  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall
which is missing the top scope autoinstall.  Because of that the indentation of the example is wrong if you just cut & paste the content.

But I do thank Andrew Lowther for helping me !  Thx Andrew !

Kind Regards,
Martin Politick, June 2022